# Resource file not being picked up when using ASP.NET expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, localization, globalization

I'm trying to use resource files in an ASP.NET Web Forms application (.NET 4.0). I'm using VS2012. I have the following files inside the `App_GlobalResources` folder:

- `Address.resx` (default language, English)
- `Address.ja-JP.resx` (Japanese)

The problem is when I'm trying to display the text in Japanese in an ASP.NET page (*.aspx file). If I use the following syntax everything works fine:

```
<%= Resources.Address.Street1 %>
```

But when I try to bind it to a property of an `asp:Label` control the default text (English) is displayed instead of Japanese:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStreet1" runat="server" Text='<%$ Resources:Address,Street1 %>'></asp:Label>
```

BTW culture is being set in session variables and then in the master page I have something like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo) Session["ci"];
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = (CultureInfo) Session["uci"];
```

Also, I don't know if this is relevant or not but I generated the `Address.ja-JP.resx` outside Visual Studio (using Notepad++) and then moved the file to the `App_GlobalResources` folder and included the file in the solution.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to my problem. In the code behind I had to override the [InitializeCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, I did something like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo) Session["ci"];
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = (CultureInfo) Session["uci"];

    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look in to using meta:resourcekey on the label control. In your case you could then use:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblStreet1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="myStreet1Label"></asp:Label>
```

The resource key in your resx files would then be like this:

```
<data name="myStreet1Label.Text">
<value xml:space="preserve">The street data.</value></data>
```

Comment: Thanks d-unit, that might work but I don't want to go that way. Too many pages are already using the expression syntax: `<%$ ... %>` :(

Comment: In that case, maybe try using HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject. <asp:Label ID="lblStreet1" runat="server" Text='<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Address", "Street1") %>' />

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `Text='<%# GetGlobalResourceObject("Address", "Street1") %>'>` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Found a solution to my problem (see my answer). Anyway thanks for your help.