# Issue with asp.net expression builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, localization

I have the same issue mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30909716/resource-file-not-being-picked-up-when-using-asp-net-expression), but the accepted answer doesn't work for me. Basically I simply would like to add translations to elements (e.g. button, label) in a webforms page.

I checked other sites too, they all point to the same solution. E.g. this this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) says:

> For example, when localizing content automatically, you can set the Text property of a server control using expression syntax, as in this example:

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" text="<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>" />
```

> In the App_GlobalResources folder, you could have resource files named Messages.resx, Messages.es.resx, Message.de.resx, and so on—a Messages resource file for each language you want to support

In my case, the translation is not picked up, I see always the neutral language (English).

I made a dummy skeleton project too with only a few lines of code, there I have 2 resource files in the `App_GlobalResources` folder:

- MyResources.resx
- MyResources.nl.resx

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl");
}
```

Default.aspx

```
<%-- this displays the translation (nl) --%>
<%= Resources.MyResource.MyKey %>
<%-- this displays the neutral language (en) --%>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: MyResource, MyKey %>" />
```

Any ideas what do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries (and failures) I got it working. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382769/localization-in-asp-net-web-forms-with-one-global-resource) and this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) put me on the right track.

In short, I needed override the `InitializeCulture` method like this:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    UICulture = "nl";
    Culture = "nl"
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("nl");
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

To make it a general solution, I had to create a new PageBase class, which is inherited by all pages, as it is nicely described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805897/masterpage-initializeculture-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-error).